# Extension on generic list with specific type?

Tags: c#, generics, extension-methods

Is it possible to create an extension method on a generic list with of a specific type for example

```
List<MyClass> myList = new List<MyClass>();

myList<MyClass>.MyExtensionMethod();
```

Its important that the MyExtensionMethod only works with a list of type MyClass.

I suspect that this is not possible so what options are there to achieve this?

Comment: Why not try it? Exactly what you "suspect is not possible" works just fine. It would have been faster to write the extension method than to come here and ask. :)

Comment: `myList` is a variable name. You cannot add generic parameters to variable names

Comment: It is possible to do this in exactly the same way as you would write any other extension method. Why not just try it?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Ofcourse it is:

```
public static void MyExtensionMethod(this List<MyClass> m)
```

It's not clear what you mean by `myList<MyClass>` but this method will work for all instances of `List<MyClass>`

Answer (score 3):

Try this :

```
 public static class ListExtensions
    {
        public static void ExtensionMethodName<T>(this List<T> list) where T : MyClass
        {
            //Code
        }

        // Or
        public static void ExtensionMethodName(this List<MyClass> list)
        {
            //Code
        }
    }
```